# SharePoint upload new document prepolulates metadata even if document is not already present in library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, file-upload, sharepoint-library

I am facing a wierd issue for one of the document.

I have one document in document library name "Tracking list of EHS.xlsx".

I downloaded this document from SharePoint to my local system and deleted the document from document library + recycle(both site and site collection).

now when I try to upload this document again to the document library some of the fields are pre-polulated even though previous document is deleted.

I renamed the document to some other name and tried again but still metadata fields are auto-populated.

Does anyone has any idea what coyuld be the reason?

Please refer attached image..

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just standard property promotion and demotion at work. The xlsx file itself contains the metadata values.

The easiest way to get rid of the metadata is to remove them from the xlsx file when you edit the file locally using Excel (under File > Info > Show all properties).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Paul.